# preg_replace remove only closing tag

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I'm working on a joomla site that use JotCache as cache component.
To exclude from cache some modules directly on template files, this component use own "markers" such as:

```
<jot myposition s> Module Position <jot myposition e>
```

Now, i'm trying to minify html trough php using DOMDocument but the result is this and the cache component doesn't work:

```
<jot myposition s> Module Position <jot myposition e></jot></jot>
```

I'm thinking to use preg_replace to strip the `</jot>` closing tag.
I tried this regex `"/<[\/]*jot[^>]*>/i"` but it strips all `<jot>` tags, including the required `<jot myposition s>` and `<jot myposition e>`.

Since I'm not sure how to accomplish this with DOMDocument (prevent tags closing automatically), how can I do this with preg_replace?

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: <jot myposition s> Module Position <jot myposition e>

Comment: To just strip the `</jot>` you can simply use this `/<\/jot>/i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Nice Chance to Explore some Regex Features!**

With all the disclaimers about using regex to work with xml-type documents... There are several interesting options for such a task.

**Option 1: Plain but Reliable**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('%(<jot.*?</jot>)</jot>%', '$1', $yourstring);
```

- Here, for safety, we match your whole string including the two `</jot>` at the end.
- The `.*?` "lazy dot-star" quantifier ensures we don't accidentally run past the first closing `</jot>`
- The parentheses capture the string you want to Group 1
- We replace with Group 1

**Option 2: More "Cheeky"**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('%</jot></jot>%', '</jot>', $yourstring);
```

- Here, we just match `</jot></jot>`
- We replace with `</jot>`

**Option 3: Futuristic**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('%</jot>(?=</jot>)%', '', $yourstring);
```

- Here, we match `</jot>`, then the lookahead `(?=</jot>)` asserts that `</jot>` can be found again, but doesn't match it.
- We replace with an empty string

**Option 4: Keep Out!**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('%<jot.*?</jot>\K</jot>%', '', $yourstring);
```

- As in the first option, `<jot.*?</jot>` matches a whole tag...
- Then `\K` tells the engine to drop whatever has been matched so far!
- and `</jot>` matches the second `</jot>`
- which we replace with the empty string

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would capture all the characters after `</` symbol and in the replacement part, it replaces the matched characters with empty string.

```
<\/.*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `<` Matches a literal `<` symbol.
- `\/` Matches forward slash `/`
- `.*$` Matches all the characters upto the last.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kU6bO2)

Your php code would be,

```
<?php
$re = '~<\/.*$~'; 
$str= '<jot myposition s> Module Position <jot myposition e></jot></jot>';
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($re, "", $str);
?>  //=> <jot myposition s> Module Position <jot myposition e>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to strip `</jot>`, why don't you use a simpler approach by using `str_replace`?

```
$output = '<jot myposition s> Module Position <jot myposition e></jot></jot>';
$output = str_replace('</jot>', '', $output);
```

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> > If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace().